# CSS Style "white-space: pre-line" not working remotely on IE 9

Tags: whitespace

I use pre-line white-space style to maintain line brakes.

```
<div style="white-space: pre-line;">
 - Item
 - Another Item
 - Third Item    
</div>
```

This work as expected locally:

 - Item

 - Another Item

 - Third Item

However when published to a remote server, line breaks are not maintained. i.e 
- Item - Another Item - Third Item

I tried multiple machines and maintaining line breaks result is the same as the following:

Manitained localy:

```
http://localhost/mysite/mypage.htm <br/>
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\mypage.htm <br/>
```

Omitted remotely, through machine name (even from the same machine), line breaks omitted:

```
http://MachineName/MySite/Mypage.htm
```

Web server is IIS 7. 
Browser IE9.

just to mention I tried Firefox and it worked successfully.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like after it is published, the browser is reading it in the wrong doc mode.

You can tell if IE9 is supporting a style rule using the Developer tool....

navigate to your page... press f12 to display the developer tool, note the Document Mode... in IE9 it MUST be IE9 to be using the latest CSS 3 style rules (You can see the mode at the top).

then use the Find tool on the Developer tool (looks like an arrow) and click on the element in your document that you want to inspect.

click on the Trace Styles tab and view the list of applied style rules to that element.... if white-space is not listed then the browser (using that document mode) is not recognizing that style rule.

Comment: I checked the trace and the white-space is applied. Any suggestion. Thanks any way.